# Java regular expression - Search string by group

Tags: java, regex

Please could someone explain this for me:

We have a regular expression which we use to check if a string matches a specific sequence. The regular expression is shown below:

```
JPRN(JAPICCTI\d{6})|(JAPICCTI\d{6})
```

I want to try and understand what this code is trying to achieve:

```
matcher = Pattern.compile("JPRN(JAPICCTI\d{6})|(JAPICCTI\d{6})");

Matcher m = matcher.matcher("JAPICCTI132323");

if(m.find()){
  Matcher m2 = matcher.matcher(m.group());
  if(m2.find()){
     return m2.replaceAll("$1")    
   }    

}
```

The string it tries to check (i.e. JAPICCTI132323) does match with the regular expression. 
I dont however understand why the matching is done twice i.e. using the string and again using the "group". What would be the reason for doing this?

And also what is the purpose of the $1 string.

This is failing because the m2.replaceAll("$1") is returning an empty string but i was expecting it to return JAPICCTI132323. Given that i dont understand what it is doing i am struggling to understand why the result is an empty string

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` symbol indicates **alternation** which means "Match the left group first, if it does not match, try the second group"

---

The `$1` symbol represents what was matched, in this case it would simply replace itself **with** itself.

---

If you have a number of capture groups: `(one\d+)(two\w+\d)(three.*?)`

Then you could use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` to represent the matched strings.

---

In other regex implementations you can name a capture group like so: `(?<first match>regexpattern)` or `(?<phone number>\d{2}\s\d{4})` but unfortunately in Java, it is not available.

---

You might have to do some testing, but you might be able to specify `$1$2` as the replacement, since if one of them is null, it won't add anything but the other match will.

But if both match, it will cause issues because you will have two strings in your replacement.

Comment: So do you mean that for m2.replaceAll to return the value i have to pass it $2 because the expression matches the second group? (i.e. the one on the right hand side of the | symbol?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The capture groups are numbered even if they do not match.

Comment: Ok that explains why m2.replaceAll("$1") is not returning anything. My problem though is how do i know at runtime which group it matched to?

Comment: I would know the number of groups the expression will have but not which one it matched to. Can i specify something like like $1|$2?

Comment: What you actually want is `(?:JAPICCTI\d{6})` - which is a non-capturing group.  That means the match for it won't be assigned to `$1, $2` or whatever.  Also, I suspect you want to escape your backslashes in your code - `"JPRN(?:JAPICCTI\\d{6})|(?:JAPICCTI\\d{6})"`

Comment: Thanks i was able to specify $1$2 - I should be able to find a solution for when both match.

Comment: Java does support named groups now (added in Java 7), but I don't know of any flavor that permits group names with spaces in them, like `(?<first match>...)` or `(?<phone number>...)`